# Call SOAP Service - Spring Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

I am migration an old project to a new technologie stack (gradle, java 8, spring 5, spring boot 2,...). Most of if already works.

But now i have problems in calling a SOAP Service. Here is the old working code

```
    URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://docsystem.intra.com:18080/documents/services?wsdl");
    String serviceName = "DocumentService";
    QName qname = new QName("http://server.priv.doc/", serviceName);
    ServiceFactory factory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();
    Service service = factory.createService(wsdlURL, qname);
    DocumentWebServiceIF imageService = (DocumentWebServiceIF) service.getPort(DocumentWebServiceIF.class);
    return imageService;
```

But this code throws now at runtime

```
org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder - Unable to locate a valid EngineConfigurationFactory


java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getEngineConfiguration(Service.java:813)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:157)
at org.apache.axis.client.ServiceFactory.createService(ServiceFactory.java:198)
```

And i have no clue how to get rid of this exception.

If i search for "spring client call soap service" i always get examples which first generate java stubs from the wsdl. I don't want this. All methodes of the service are returning just byte arrays. So in the end i am seraching for a simple  solution to call a soap service.

Comment: `But this code throws now at runtime` Please add the codes.

Comment: There are no more log messages...no stacktrace is printed out

Comment: wrap this code with try/catch and see if you are able to print the stacktrace

Comment: if wraped the code with catch(Throwable). Now i have a stacktrace. I post in in the question.